# ApplicativeDo not working with sequencing

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, do-notation

I have this type, basically a Kleisli arrow:

```
{-# language DeriveFunctor #-}

data Plan m i o = Plan  (i -> m o) deriving Functor

instance (Monad m) => Applicative (Plan m i) where
    pure x = Plan (\_ -> pure x)
    Plan f <*> Plan x = Plan (\i -> f i <*> x i)
```

Since it has an `Applicative` instance, I turn on `ApplicativeDo` and try to build a value using do-notation:

```
{-# language ApplicativeDo #-}

myplan :: Plan IO () ()
myplan = do
    pure ()
    pure ()
```

It doesn't work:

```
No instance for (Monad (Plan IO ())) arising from a do statement
```

Is there a way to make it work? I'm using GHC 8.0.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching for `ApplicativeDo`-related tickets in the [GHC Trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc), it appears that is is a known problem:

- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10892
- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12666

---

Explicitly discarding the result is a workaround:

```
do
  _ <- pure ()
  pure ()
```

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicativeDo` does not mean that `do` expressions will *always* be desugared in terms of an applicative functor, but only if it makes sense to do so. Here, it does not. If you have a `do` expression like

```
do
  x <- someAction
  y <- someAction
  return (x + y)
```

note that the order doesn't really matter, so you could desugar this to

```
pure (+) <*> someAction <*> someAction
```

instead of

```
someAction >>= (\x -> someAction >>= (\y -> return (x + y))
```

However, the expression

```
do
  pure ()
  pure ()
```

doesn't have any way of being expressed using `pure` and `<*>` alone. It is *not* equivalent to `pure () <*> pure ()`, because the first value wraps `()`, not a function. Since there is no valid way to desugar this using only an `Applicative` instance, the compiler looks for, and fails to find, a `Monad` instance to allow `pure () >> pure ()`.

Comment: It could be `pure () *> pure ()` though. Why doesn't it do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a reason other than "it doesn't". There might be an underlying reason why `a >> b` and `a *> b` could be subtlety different, or it could just be that the initial implementation of the desugaring restricts itself to `fmap` and `<*>` for simplicity.

Comment: @chepner When I write each statement like `_ <- pure ()` it seems to work.

Comment: Like I said, there may not be a good reason, but as it currently stands, it simply does not. See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ApplicativeDo; it only discusses the `<*>` operator, and makes no mention of `*>` or `<*`.

Comment: I'm not certain but I doubt this is intentional; you should file a feature request on Trac.

Comment: Apparently, this is a known limitation: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10892 https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12666