# ApplicativeDo language extension with `Parsing` applicative still looking for Monad instance

Tags: haskell, ghc, applicative

I'm trying to write a parser using the `parsers` [package](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.0/parsers-0.12.4/Text-Parser-Token.html#t:TokenParsing) using `do` syntax. Here is an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}
import Text.Parser.Char (string, spaces)
import Text.Parser.Token (TokenParsing, natural)

issueParser :: TokenParsing p => p Integer
issueParser = do
  spaces
  string "**Issue:**"
  spaces
  string "https://github.com" <|> string "github.com"
  string "/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/"
  natural
```

The error GHC gives me is `Could not deduce (Monad p) arising from a do statement from the context: TokenParsing p`. This error message is correct that `TokenParsing` does not provide `Monad` as a super class, however it does provide `Applicative` which means because I have this language extension turned on, I should be able to use the `do` syntax with just `Applicative`. What am I doing wrong/missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out. To get this example to work on ghc 8.0.2 you would need to add underscore generators, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}
import Text.Parser.Char (string, spaces)
import Text.Parser.Token (TokenParsing, natural)

issueParser :: TokenParsing p => p Integer
issueParser = do
  _ <- spaces
  _ <- string "**Issue:**"
  _ <- spaces
  _ <- string "https://github.com" <|> string "github.com"
  _ <- string "/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/"
  n <- natural
  pure n
```

There is already a ghc bug to address this here: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12666

Comment: Oh wow, I am surprised to see that `ApplicativeDo` did not handle this rather obvious case!

Comment: `ApplicativeDo` is quite dumb.  E.g. it can't handle a `let` statement of any sort whatsoever

Comment: I had a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210599/applicativedo-not-working-with-sequencing

Comment: Oh look at that. I'm surprised that this question didn't show up in my search. It is very similar